# CallKit CXCallController.request error com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=6 while app is in the background

Tags: ios, swift, voip, callkit

This error only occurs in iOS 13.3.1. It does not occur on iOS 13.3.0 or earlier.

If the app is in the foreground and it calls `CXCallController.request`, it works fine. But once I background the app and execute 'CXCallController.request' (triggered by the headphone play button), I get the following error:

```
Error requesting transaction: Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=6 "(null)"
```

Code 6 is `CXErrorCodeRequestTransactionError.Code.invalidAction`

Here's a snippet of the sample code

```
let uuid = UUID()
let handle = CXHandle(type: .emailAddress, value: "jappleseed@apple.com")

let startCallAction = CXStartCallAction(call: uuid, handle: handle)

let transaction = CXTransaction(action: startCallAction)
callController.request(transaction) { error in
    if let error = error {
        print("Error requesting transaction: \(error)")
    } else {
        print("Requested transaction successfully")
    }
}
```

The same code works fine in iOS 13.3.0 and earlier regardless if the app is foreground or background. Maybe this is a 13.3.1 bug or maybe Apple implemented some security measure while apps is in the background? But I don't see it in the iOS 13.3.1 release notes.

Comment: Are you by chance compiling with Xcode 10? Does the issue happen if you compile with Xcode 11?

Comment: I'm compiling with Xcode 11. There's a work around. Something has changed in iOS 13.3.1. Now you have start playing an audio first and then you can call the request method.

Comment: care to add a snippet for the workaround you’ve found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a work around to my own question. It may only work to my specific condition. It may not solve the problem for all error code=6. Just so you know.

The way to fix this is that you have to be playing audio before you call `CXCallController.request(:)` when your app is in the background. You can even play a silent sound for a second if you want. It doesn't have to be an audible sound.

If it doesn't work, you can try using dispatch async with a 0.1 second delay to call `CXCallController.request(:)`. The idea is that you need to make sure the audio engine is active when you call `CXCallController.request(:)`.

Comment: none of them worked out. Any other suggestions?